# Checking multiple values in array with another array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects `A` obtained from JSON data which is like:

```
[Object { field1="2381", field2="1233", field3="46.44852", more...},
Object { field1="2381", field2="1774", field3="45.70752833333334", more...}]
```

And I have another array `B` like

```
["2381", "1187"]
```

Is there a way to check if values of this array `B` exists in array `A`?

I tried with something like

```
A.map((B[0], B[1]), function(element) {
    if (B[0] == element.field1 && B[1] == element.field2) 
        return true; 
    else 
        return false; 
});
```

but it didn't worked well...

Any trick?

Comment: See if this helps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if there's at least one item in A that matches B.

```
A.some(function(value) {
    return value.field1 == B[0] && value.field2 == B[1];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like this one :

```
function check(arr, fn) {
    var i = 0, l = arr.length;
    for (; i < l; i++) {
        if (fn(arr[i])) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage :

```
var A, B;

A = [
    { field1: 1, field2: 2 },
    { field1: 1, field2: 3 },
    { field1: 2, field2: 3 }
];

B = [1, 3];
check(A, function (item) {
    return item.field1 === B[0] && item.field2 === B[1];
}); // true

B = [2, 1];
check(A, function (item) {
    return item.field1 === B[0] && item.field2 === B[1];
}); // false
```

Comment: You mean arr is my array A and fn is array B ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested for loop.  Something along the lines of:

```
 var checker; //number to hold the current value
for(x=0;x<arrayA.length; x++) //loop through the first array
{
  checker = arrayA[x]; store the number in each element in the variable
 for(y=array.Indexof(arrayA, checker);y<arrayB.length; y++) /*don't start from the very first index of the array but rather from the last place where arrayA was*/
  {
   if (arrayB[y] == checker)
     {
   Alert(checker + " is the same");
 }//closes if
}//closes for
}//closes outer for loop
```

Obviously you would substitue the alert for your particular needs.  My syntax may be a little off but you get the gist.  Hope this helps...